# Disable div (with background image) using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and I would like to disable the resize of the div when I resize the web browser window. I want to do this because i have a div inside that div (for a drag and drop), so every time the window gets resized the second div changes it's position on the background.
The problem is occuring in the **div with id=1**, i wannt it to have a fixed size, so every time I resize the browser it stays with the same size, allowinng the div inside it to not change it's position.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Index</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="home.html">home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="building.html">Building</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="truck.html">Truck</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div>
        <div class="myNewDivHeight2">
            <img id="drag1" src="images/truck.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="bgimg myNewDivHeight" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <div class="hsonuc">DIV</div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <hr class="featurette-divider">
</div>


<script src="js/JS_casa.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) { //this is to allways show the background image of the div
.myNewDivHeight{
    min-height: 390px;
    }
}

.hsonuc {
position:absolute;
background-color: white;
top:72%;
right:50%;
margin-right:200px;
}
```

This is how it looks when gets resized: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htkZk.jpg

Edit: adde more code

Comment: Well this is quite hard to understand with just that code.

Comment: I just added more code.